# How to partially modify a CSS theme in eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a bundle which contains a number of widgets which can be used by a number of RCP applications. I want to provide a standard set of CSS styles for these widgets which will be packaged in the widget bundle.

Normally, these standard styles should be ok but I would like to be able to define new styles in an application bundle which overwrites just one or two styles but leaving the rest intact.

Is this possible? What I've seen so far, is that when my application bundle defines a new theme extension, all other styles are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html

In `plugin.xml` add a `themeAssociation` item to the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme` extention point. Set the association to the theme defined in the other plugin.

In my case it looks like this:

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme">
      <themeAssociation
            colorAndFontId="org.eclipse.ui.ide.systemDefault"
            themeId="com.acme.indu40.rcp.core.theme">
      </themeAssociation>
      <theme
            basestylesheeturi="default.css"
            id="special.theme"
            label="Special Theme">
      </theme>
   </extension>
```

The main theme is defined in `com.acme.indu40.rcp.core` and this is merged with `default.css` in the local plugin.

Possibly the better way is to import styles in the stylesheet:

```
@import url("platform:/plugin/com.acme.indu40.rcp.core/default.css");
```